# Evaluate the lateral surface defined by a set rotated 360 degree around the z axis

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

Let $D=\left\{(y,z): \sqrt{y} \leq z \leq 2-\sqrt{y} \right\}$. Rotate $D$ $360$ degree around the $z$ axis generating the volume $V_z$ and evaluate the lateral surface of $V_z$, $|\partial V_z|$.

For evaluating the lateral surface of $V_z$, I considered these two curves:

- $\gamma_1(t) = (t,\sqrt{t})$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$;
- $\gamma_2(t) = (t,2- \sqrt{t})$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

So I continued by doing the integral $$|\partial V_z| = 2\pi\int_{0}^{1}t\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4t}}dt +2\pi\int_{0}^{1}t\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4t}}dt = 4\pi\int_{0}^{1}t\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4t}}dt.$$

Any tips on how to solve this integral? Is it possible to evaluate the surface with a different approach?

Comment: You can get it to standard $\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ form and then either apply the formula or integrate by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface area of a solid of revolution around the $z$-axis is given by
$$S = 2\pi\int_{a}^{b} f(z) \sqrt{1 + f'(z)^{2}}\, dz.$$
In your case we have two functions: $f_1(z)=z^2$ (from $z=\sqrt{y}$) over the interval $[0,1]$ and $f_2(z)=(2-z)^2$ (from $z=2-\sqrt{y}$) over the interval $[1,2]$. Therefore
$$|\partial V_z|=2\pi\int_{0}^{1} f_1(z) \sqrt{1 + f_1'(z)^{2}}\, dz+2\pi\int_{1}^{2} f_2(z) \sqrt{1 + f_2'(z)^{2}}\, dz$$
Note that, by symmetry, the two integrals are equal. Moreover
$$\int_{0}^{1} f_1(z) \sqrt{1 + f_1'(z)^{2}}\, dz=\int_{0}^{1} z^2 \sqrt{1 + 4z^2}\, dz=\int_{0}^{\text{arcsinh}(2)}\cosh^2(t)\sinh^2(t)\,dt$$
where we applied the substitution $2z=\sinh(t)$. Can you take it from here? You may also take a look at [How to evaluate integral: $\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}\;dx.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079890/how-to-evaluate-integral-int-x2-sqrtx21-dx)

P.S. Your approach is correct and after letting $t=z^2$ we find the same integral
$$\int_{0}^{1}t\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4t}}\,dt=\int_{0}^{1} z^2 \sqrt{1 + 4z^2}\, dz.$$
I don't see an easier way to find this area.

Comment: Thanks. Starting from your hint, $$I = \int_{0}^{\log(1+\sqrt{2})}\frac{1}{8} \left( \cosh(4t)-1 \right)dt = \dots = \frac{1}{32}\left[ \sinh(4t)\right]_{0}^{\log(1+\sqrt{2})}-\frac{1}{8}\left(\log(1+\sqrt{2}) \right ) = \frac{3\sqrt{2}-\log(1+\sqrt{2})}{8}.$$ So that $$|\partial V_z|=4\pi \cdot I = \pi\frac{3\sqrt{2}-\log(1+\sqrt{2})}{2}.$$ Is that right?

Comment: Yes, as soon as we take the correct upper limit $\text{arcsinh}(2)=\log(\sqrt{5}+2)$ (I edited my answer with the right one, sorry)